# System.AccessViolationException with Marshal

Tags: c#, c++, .net, marshalling

I have some problem with call my unmanaged function from c#.
In duration of the method call I face to System.AccessViolationException.
I realy don't know why it happends. Could you specify me where is my mistake.

A bit dig around, i found one tip about type mapping mistake and tried different arguments types, but it didn't help.

C# methods call

```cs
var result = delegates.CalculateGHDelegate(16, 68, true, true, error, 25);

public delegate int CalculateGHDelegate(int labId, int ghId, bool isFailStep2,
 bool isHandleStep2, string errorText, int errorTextLength);
```

C++ function code

```cpp
int __stdcall Calc(int num_lab, int num_rec, bool isFailStep2, 
        bool isHandleStep2, char *errorText, const int errorTextLen)
```

Comment: I assume the method will write to the buffer provided in errorText. You should change "string" to "StringBuilder" in your C# declaration. And don't forget to actually allocate space for 25 characters in it. One more: you need to specify ANSI char set for the method as it uses char* not wchar_t*.